# How "String Split" method works?

Tags: apex, string, split

How "String Split" method works for the below snippet?

```
String emailAddress = 'test@test.com,test1@test.com,';
```

There is no value after the second comma. Even it will not throw any errors but I just need to know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those things where it's definitely quicker to just try it for yourself and inspect the debug log.

Splitting on `,` will give you a list of size 2. The final element of the list would be an empty string (because there's nothing after the final delimiter), but it appears that Salesforce doesn't put that into the resulting list.

Comment: Exactly. I have also inspected it using the debug logs and it's giving size of the list as 2. So just wanted to know the concept behind it because there is nothing after the comma.

Comment: List size would be 3.

Comment: @AdrianLarson No, the size will be 2.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I initially thought it would be size 3 too, but running it anon gives me a list of size 2. Maybe that got changed in a recent-ish release (coulda sworn it should have been size 3).

Comment: That's a bug IMO. Output size should always be one more than the delimiter count.